# Problem with character array input and output in C

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to read a character array and print it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
void read_array(char a[],int n);
void print_array(char a[],int n);
int main(void)
{
    char a[100];
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the characters:");
    read_array(a,n);
    printf("\nThe array now is: ");
    print_array(a,n);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void read_array(char a[],int n)
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         scanf("%c",&a[i]);

}
void print_array(char a[],int n)
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)                
        printf("a[%d]=%c\n",i,a[i]);
}
```

**Input:**

```
Enter n:15  
Enter the characters:xxxxx     xxxxx
```

**Output:**

```
The array now is:  
a[0]=    
a[1]=x    
a[2]=x    
a[3]=x    
a[4]=x    
a[5]=x    
a[6]=    
a[7]=    
a[8]=    
a[10]=    
a[11]=x    
a[12]=x   
a[13]=x    
a[14]=x
```

Where in my input `a[5]` through `a[9]` are **blank** characters. So how come in the output `a[0]=(a blank)`?

Comment: Are you sure it's blank? Or does your output have a blank line between `a[0]=` and `a[1]=`

Comment: Rolled back. Input and output belong in quote blocks, not code blocks.

Comment: @GEOCHET, says who?  What if the I/O doesn't make sense without fixed-width formatting?  Not to mention some highlighting comes for free with code blocks.  Meta also seems to disagree with you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52502

Comment: @carl: Syntax highlighting is useless on non code blocks and <pre> works just fine for fixed width.

Comment: I have to go with @GEOCHET here, syntax highlighting is usually annoying for non-code blocks. However, pre tag _was_ required here since the spacing is important in all those x's (so I added it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character you're reading in is the newline you typed to enter the `15`.  Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` - you'll be much happier.

Comment: doesn't scanf skip over all the whitespaces.

Comment: @user567797, that depends on how you use it, I guess.  That's the normal use case, though.  You can just use `getch()` for your second set of input if that makes it easier.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `*scanf` here (for the string anyway, you still need it for the number) since `fgets` will _give_ you a string. And, if you're looking for a robust input method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130723/is-this-vulnerable-to-a-stack-overflow/5130782#5130782

Answer (score 1):

In the scanf function for getting the values of character use getche or getchar function. This will allow you to capture all the characters including new line. you can skip the first character and copy the rest.

Answer (score 0):

While taking input in case of char array using scanf, it also captures the enter key that you presses while entering the input on a new line, so this problem is happening.

```
You may use getchar if you want each character to be present as input.
```