# 2d array in c p

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 int i=0,j=0;
 char a[5][2];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<2;j++){
   scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
  }
 }
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<2;j++){
   printf("\n %c \n",a[i][j]);
   printf("\t");
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

i/p:
an
gu
sd
ec

I get no output.

I was trying a simple program on 2d arrays. I could not get the output and the input is not taking 5*2 characters instead it takes only 4*2 characters.

Comment: This can be problem with reading char using `scanf`, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556622/problem-with-character-array-input-and-output-in-c

Comment: Are you hitting enter after each line of input? Because I am running your program, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Are you intending on each major index in your array containing the two chars in each *pair*? If so, is there any particular reason you're providing 4 pairs and (trying to) scanning 5 pairs on input?

Comment: [This works as expected.](http://ideone.com/ArzExL) I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @H2CO3 try it with `01 23 45 67` =P

Comment: @WhozCraig `01 23 45 7` [works fine too.](http://ideone.com/ArzExL)

Comment: @H2CO3 I concur, but I think your and my definition of "work" differs from what he wants. The code does *exactly* what you or I expect it would do, but I think he wants each *pair* to be in a separate *row* in the array. Hard saying without more input from the OP.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah. But in that case, wouldn't it be sufficient to swap the rows and columns in the array? Or isn't that what you're saying?

Comment: @H2CO3 I *think* he's looking for something [like this](http://ideone.com/Od2MuU), but again, its hard saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahaaaa! I see. Well... Lesson learned: if you're a beginner, don't you dare using `scanf()`. (I am not brave enough to use it either, because `scanf()` does not do what one thinks it does. `fgets()` and functions from `<string.h>` are *the* way to go when parsing user input.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

paste my code,give one space before %c.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
     int i=0,j=0;
     char a[5][2];
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(j=0;j<2;j++){
       scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
      }
     }
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(j=0;j<2;j++){
       printf("\n %c \n",a[i][j]);
       printf("\t");
      }
      printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah . Its working fine with the change. But why do we need to give a space before %c in the scanf.

Comment: @Angus to tell `scanf()` to ignore zero-or-more whitespace chars on the way to the requested formatted input type.

Answer (score 0):

In you input spaces are also being considered as char,because of which it is seeming to you that only 4*2 input is being taken.Give input without space and you will be able to enter 5*2 char.

Answer (score -3):

The reason is the data type you used in scanf( "%c" ).

Since the Table, NewLine, Space are all available chars. So if you insert some thing like :

```
 a \n
```

a[0][0] will be 'a', and a[0][1] will be '\n'.

This conclusion can be verified if you use the following code to test:

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                                                                           
int main(){
  int i=0,j=0;
  int a[5][2];
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
      printf("i=%d,j=%d:\n",i,j);
      scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
      printf("\n %d \n",a[i][j]);
      printf("\t");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't even *compile*.

Comment: Not only you didn't read the question, you also suggest using bad practice (using `malloc` for temporaries **and** casting its return value).